# Django REST: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'trips'

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm having problems to make my Serializer work.

I have models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)

class Trip(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='trips')
    city = models.ForeignKey('locations.City', related_name='trips')
    date_from = models.DateField(default=now)
    date_to = models.DateField(default=now)
    detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm trying to create a serializer and a view, which returns all cities in which user has at least one trip, and for every city, list of the trips (only for this user).

```
def ajax_get_my_trips(request):
    trips = Trip.objects.all()
    cities = City.objects.filter(trips__in=trips)
    response = MyCityTripsSerializer(cities).data
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)

class MyTripsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ('date_from', 'date_to', 'detail')

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Trip.objects.filter(user=user)


class MyCityTripsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trips = MyTripsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('place_id', 'lat', 'lng', 'number_of_users_here_now', 'formatted_address', 'trips')
```

My expectation for example if user was two times in London and once in Prague:

```
[{<serialized London>,'trips':[<serialized the two London trips>]},
{<serialized Prague>, 'trips':[<serialized one trip to Prague]}]
```

But when I perform get request, it returns:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `trips` on
>   serializer `MyCityTripsSerializer`. The serializer field might be
>   named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet`
>   instance. Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no
>   attribute 'trips'.

Do you know how to avoid this error or how to do it other way?

Comment: At `response = MyCityTripsSerializer(cities).data`, you are passing in a `QuerySet` of `City` objects. Did you mean `response = MyCityTripsSerializer(cities, many=True).data` instead?

Comment: Oh, thanks... what a shame.